# How to make android's DatePickerDialog use Serbian Latin locale instead of Cyrillic

Tags: android, localization, locale, datepickerdialog

I want to DatePickerDialog use Serbian Latin letters instead of Serbian Cyrillic. My application have option to choose between Serbian and English and I have directories `values` and `values-sr`.

I am using this to change locale programmatically inside my application:
http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

And I have override `attachBaseContext()` method in each activity/fragment.

However when I change to Serbian language, in my application datepicker uses Cyrillic letters

[image]

This is the code how I create DatePickerDialog:

```
private void openDatePickerDialog() {
    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
            // ...
        }
    };


    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.AppTheme_DatePickerDialogTheme, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.show();
}
```